# Add a different 'reply to' Email address in MailDefinition C#

Tags: c#, email

I am using Windows Form Application which is sending HTML emails using MailDefinition Class.

```
MailDefinition mailDefinition = new MailDefinition();
mailDefinition.BodyFileName = strfilename;
mailDefinition.From = "email@company.com";
```

Is it possible that somehow I can add a different email id where user will reply. I don't want the users to reply on this `email@company.com` email id.

I am looking for some thing like this:

```
mail.Headers.Add( "Reply-To", "alternate_email@mycompany.com")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient class which has a send method that takes a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage parameter.

In the MailMessage class it has: replyTo and replyToList properties.

Add HTML content like this:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
m.Body = "HTML Content";
m.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: But how did you filled HTML contents by using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient class

Comment: In the message body of the MailMessage class: 
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
m.Body = "HTML Content";
m.IsBodyHtml = true;

Comment: Can you send me a link here ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I still couldn't got the point, how did you filled in the HTML file contents from database ? I have an HTML file and I want to fill its contents and then send the email.

Comment: Contruct the HTML into a string e.g. string x = string.format("<HTML><BODY><P>{0}</P></BODY></HTML>",textbox1.text); Then assign x to m.Body. The smtpclient class is only used to send the email the MailMessage class is used to create the email.